# Drupal 6: CCK field is being hidden

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, cck

I've been trying to add a custom fields into a custom content type, everything is good except the new field is not displayed though it appears in the `HTML` with `display: none;` attributes, also new field isn't excluded from the display.

What is the problem here?

Sultan

Comment: When you look in the CSS file, from where does the `display: none;` come from ? Wich file ?

Comment: It comes as the attribute of a parent element

Comment: this is how it looks `<div class="hide-field alpha grid-16" style="display:none;">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used CSS to hide another CCK field somewhere?

It sounds like a CSS rule was meant to hide another CCK field but was not specific enough and is now accidentally hiding fields you want to see.

For example, if you have a CSS rule of:

```
div.field {
  display: none;
}
```

meaning to hide a different field, it will hide all your CCK fields. (it may not be `div.field` of course)

Comment: It's not excluded from the display, and no css rules

Comment: you were right. And the reason is that this came from the `node` templates

Answer (score 0):

If it has `display: none` it's not showing up. Change it do `display: block` or just remove it.